Non-locality of the wavefunction in QM and Twistor theory
Regarding locality, I don't think locality is a principle per se, but we often assume that the physical fields are local on spacetime, describable by partial differential equations and so on. But of course, we know that in QM, a wave function is not local in spacetime, as can be seen in the thought experiment of measuring a property of one of two entangled particles that have been separated very far from each other.
My question is, can locality be restored if we view a wavefunction as defined on an auxiliary space? I am thinking about the twistor space, for example. A field that lives in a small region of twistor space, corresponds to an extended region in spacetime (each point in twistor space corresponds to an $\alpha$-plane in complexified Minkowski spacetime).
So if we think of a wavefunction as living on a twistor space (or perhaps some other "auxiliary" space), can we then say that it is local as a function on twistor space, thus restoring locality?
I haven't been following twistor theory literature closely (and I don't know the literature well), but I thought it would be an interesting question to ask, hoping to get some interesting comments and answers from which I would learn something new.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'm closing this question as unclear since the notion of "locality" used in the question is unclear, as well as how twistor theory is supposed to relate to it.

The discussion in the comments seems to be a classical example of miscommunication. People don't exactly define what they means by the terms that are used. Before, attempting to answer the OP question, I'll first clear up some of these misconceptions.
One terms that is particularly misused is the term nonlocal. One can often, even in classical physics, observe correlations between measurements made at different location. That is not what nonlocal means. In physics the concept of nonlocality is associated with what Einstein called "spooky action at a distance" the operator term being "action." So, nonlocality would be the ability to do something at one point of spacetime and thus affecting something at another point with a space-like separation. That does not happen in physical reality, not even in quantum physics, nor is it associated with quantum entanglement.
... which bring me to another misleading concept: Does that mean that quantum entanglement is nothing more than classical correlations? No quantum entanglement is something different and cannot be explained with classical physics. When Bell derived his inequality, he made two assumptions the one was locality; the other was a unique reality. The violation of Bell's inequality that was observed thus implies that one of these assumptions are wrong. If locality remains in tact, then it must be the assumption about a unique reality that must be wrong.
What does it mean that we don't have a unique reality? Is it like the many worlds interpretation? Almost. However, since quantum interpretations cannot be ruled out by physical observation they are all equivalent when it comes to explaining anything that we can observe. To help us understand what is going on, we can pick any interpretation. So, I'll pick the many worlds interpretation but strip it with the nonsense of multi-universe and branching. We can just think of it as multiple realities. Considering a Bell state, each of the two terms represents a separate reality. If a measurement produces a result that corresponds one of the terms in the Bell state, a measurement on the other particle will produce the corresponding result from the same term. The way that we make sure that these results are part of the same reality is that the people that made the measurements must communicate their results to each other.
Now for the OP question. In effect the preceding discussion already addressed the question. Locality is alive and well in quantum physics, entanglement and all. It is indeed a basic principle of physics. There is therefore no need to try and restore it with twistor theory are anything else.

I just wanted to mention that, while my post wasn't clear enough, yet your answer is useful. So I could have edited the post, made it clearer, and your answer would have clarified things. To me it wasn't clear that the right interpretation of EPR, in order to avoid a paradox, is to keep locality but reject realism! Realism is an assumption so deeply ingrained in our brains... And this is why your answer is interesting. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Oh, I see it was @ACuriousMind who closed it. Please read my previous comment, regarding flippiefanus's useful answer. But I guess it is too late now, of course.
